# URL serialization does not work after page refresh

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm facing a problem with emberJS and the Router.

My route architecture is the one below :

- root

  - index
  - app

    - home
    - item

      - display/:id
      - edit/:id

When I initialy navigate to display/:id the URL is well written as below :

```
localhost/#/app/item/display/da083d21-afab-4620-8a85-6a4e6bfb95b9
```

Then I hit the refresh button of my browser and the URL is then written as

```
localhost/#/app/item/display/undefined
```

I have the following functions in my route to handle serialize/deserialize

```
deserialize:  function(router, context) {
    return App.Item.find(context.id);
},
serialize:  function(router, context){
    return { id: context.id };
}
```

When I log the context passed in serialize :

- before the refresh : it is set to the right item
- after the refresh : it is set to an element that does not contained the id (not my item)

So I guess I'm missing something to serialize my URL after page refresh.

Any lead ?

Thanks

Comment: could you log the context inside the deserialize method ? even better, could you provide a jsfiddle of you example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was already address in [Emberjs async routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034375/emberjs-async-routing)

Solution is to use a Deferred object and implement the loading state.

Hope that helps